# selected index of datalist contains checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i have a datalist contains checkboxlist.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlstfilter" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBoxList ForeColor="Gray"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chklist_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="chklist"
   runat="server">
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

can i get the rownumber of datalist on the SelectedIndexChanged event of the checkbox ie;if i have checkbox list control repeated 4times  and if i check on the second one how can i get the value 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try fetch parent of checkboxlist like this

```
 Protected void dtlstfilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var control= ((Control)sender).Parent;
    if(control is DataListItem)
    {
       int index=((DataListItem)control).ItemIndex;
    }
}
```

if you not get DataListItem as parent then try parent of parent.

Answer (score 0):

U can Try Following. I added +1 as it is 0 based index..

```
Protected void dtlstfilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSelectedIndex.Text = (dtlstfilter.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString();
    }
```